# Reading private queues using a windows service listener

Tags: msmq

I am trying to read queue messages from a private queue in the local system using a service. I have created the service which reads the queue and updates status to an access DB. I have setup the service and the service is up and running. I am stuck with how to go about using the service in a asp.net application to read the queue. Should I create a DLL and reference it and it should be fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try to make the service also act as some sort of server (WCF) to listen for requests (as well as processing the private queue). Then your asp.net could connect to it and request whatever info it needs from it.

This service could then be your only entry point to the queue and any other application you write could go through it to access the queue.